# java gui form image not showing dialog message not working

Tags: java, user-interface

I would like to insert an image into my `JFrame` but it is not showing. The image file is "a.jpg"

This is the output I get

[image]

Here is my code.

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class myself extends JFrame
{   
    public myself()
    {
        super("Introduction to myself");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JLabel jl = new JLabel("Name");
        JTextField jtf = new JTextField("random name",20);
        jtf.setEnabled(false);
        jtf.setBackground(Color.gray);
        jl.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
        add(jl);
        add(jtf);

        JLabel jl1 = new JLabel("Date of Birth");
        JTextField jtf1 = new JTextField("not today",20);
        jtf1.setEnabled(false);
        jtf1.setBackground(Color.gray);
        jl1.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        add(jl1);
        add(jtf1);

        JLabel jl2 = new JLabel("Email");
        JTextField jtf2 = new JTextField("thisismyemail@gmail.com",20);
        jtf2.setEnabled(false);
        jtf2.setBackground(Color.gray);
        jl2.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
        add(jl2);
        add(jtf2);

        ImageIcon ic = new ImageIcon("a.jpg");
        JLabel jl3 = new JLabel("My comments to the subject, will update further", ic, SwingConstants.LEFT);
        jl3.setToolTipText ("I am rabbit");
        add(jl3);

        JTextField comment1 = new JTextField(20);
        add(comment1);

        JTextField comment2 = new JTextField(20);
        add(comment2);

        comment1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            String c1 = comment1.getText();
            String c2 = comment2.getText();
            String s = "1. " + c1 + " 2. " + c2;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, s, "My suggestion to the course", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }
        });

        comment2.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            String c1 = comment1.getText();
            String c2 = comment2.getText();
            String s = String.format("1. " + c1 + " 2. " + c2);

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, s, "My suggestion to the course", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }
        });
    }
}

class Lab3
{
    public static void main (String [ ] args)
    {
        myself ms = new myself();
        ms.setSize(200, 300);
        ms.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ms.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Also, apart from the image problem, I am also facing problem with my `ActionListener`.
I would like to get this as my output, after I finish typing in the text boxes and hit ENTER

[image]

But this is what I get with the code I have right now.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Change name of class `myself` to `Myself` according to [java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html)
2. Use a more appropriate layout manager. `GridBagLayout` is good for forms that contain `JLabel` and `JTextField` pairs. Refer to [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)
3. Your image file is not found. According to your code, it is supposed to be in the current working directory which is the value returned by this code.

```java
System.getProperty("user.dir")
```

Refer to [How to Use Icons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html)

4. In order for the `actionPerformed()` method to correctly display the text from `comment1` and `comment2`, you need to get the text from inside the method. Refer to [Nested Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)
5. Call method [pack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack--) rather than `setSize()`.
6. Consider also calling method [setLocationByPlatform](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setLocationByPlatform-boolean-)

Here is my refactored version of your code.

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class Lab3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Myself ms = new Myself();
        ms.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ms.pack();
        ms.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        ms.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class Myself extends JFrame {
    public Myself() {
        super("Introduction to myself");
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        JLabel jl = new JLabel("Name");
        JTextField jtf = new JTextField("random name", 20);
        jtf.setEnabled(false);
        jtf.setBackground(Color.gray);
        jl.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
        add(jl, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        add(jtf, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        JLabel jl1 = new JLabel("Date of Birth");
        JTextField jtf1 = new JTextField("not today", 20);
        jtf1.setEnabled(false);
        jtf1.setBackground(Color.gray);
        jl1.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        add(jl1, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        add(jtf1, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        JLabel jl2 = new JLabel("Email");
        JTextField jtf2 = new JTextField("thisismyemail@gmail.com", 20);
        jtf2.setEnabled(false);
        jtf2.setBackground(Color.gray);
        jl2.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
        add(jl2, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        add(jtf2, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        ImageIcon ic = new ImageIcon("a.jpg");
        JLabel jl3 = new JLabel("My comments to the subject, will update further",
                                ic,
                                SwingConstants.LEFT);
        jl3.setToolTipText("I am rabbit");
        add(jl3, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        JTextField comment1 = new JTextField(20);
        add(comment1, gbc);

        gbc.gridy = 4;
        JTextField comment2 = new JTextField(20);
        add(comment2, gbc);

        comment1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String c1 = comment1.getText();
                String c2 = comment2.getText();
                String s = "1. " + c1 + " 2. " + c2;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Myself.this, s, "My suggestion to the course",
                        JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }
        });

        comment2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String c1 = comment1.getText();
                String c2 = comment2.getText();
                String s = String.format("1. " + c1 + " 2. " + c2);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Myself.this, s, "My suggestion to the course",
                        JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And this is how it looks when I run the above code.

[image: Running app.]

Comment: For a better user experience, I would have laid out the "My comments" JLabel and the following two JTextFields across two grid bag columns (gbc.gridwidth = 2).